# Export vim syntax highlighting to latex

Tags: vim, latex

I would like to exploit vim's syntax highlighting capabilities to highlight code (any language) in latex (using the xcolor package). Therefore I wonder if it is possible to have a vim-script export the vim internal information about the highlighted text in the buffer. Obviously it would be sufficient to know start, end and color of each highlighted entity. The generation of the latex code or other languages such as html would then be obvious.

Comment: Then why not export directly to HTML? Regex matching groups to LaTeX is a bit more complicated :/

Comment: do you know about the listing package http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use my [formatvim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3113) plugin: it can export to latex-xcolor format with

```
Format format latex-xcolor
```

. If you are not fine with the result (it is completely untested and I almost never used this option) feel free to send patches, dictionary with format specification can be seen [here](http://formatvim.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/formatvim/formatvim/file/5d58c4424e9a/plugin/format.vim#l752), everything what you need to create your own format is in [documentation](http://vimpluginloader.sourceforge.net/doc/format.txt.html).

Note: if you need to export to any other language all you need is to write a specification for it in terms of my plugin. Here is a code that will add `latex-xcolor-clone` format to my plugin:

```
scriptencoding utf-8
execute frawor#Setup('0.0', {'plugin/format': '3.0'})
let s:texescape=
            \'substitute('.
            \   'substitute(@@@, ''\v[\\\[\]{}&$_\^%#]'', '.
            \              '''\=''''\char''''.char2nr(submatch(0))."{}"'', '.
            \              '"g"),'.
            \'" ", ''\\enskip{}'', "g")'
let s:texstylestart=
            \'((@inverse@)?'.
            \   '(''\colorbox[HTML]{''.'.
            \    '((@fgcolor@!=#"")?'.
            \       '(toupper(@fgcolor@[1:])):'.
            \       '(toupper(@_fgcolor@[1:])))."}{".'.
            \   '''\textcolor[HTML]{''.'.
            \    '((@bgcolor@!=#"")?'.
            \       '(toupper(@bgcolor@[1:])):'.
            \       '(toupper(@_bgcolor@[1:])))."}{"):'.
            \   '(((@bgcolor@!=#"")?'.
            \       '(''\colorbox[HTML]{''.toupper(@bgcolor@[1:])."}{"):'.
            \       '("")).'.
            \    '''\textcolor[HTML]{''.'.
            \    '((@fgcolor@!=#"")?'.
            \       '(toupper(@fgcolor@[1:])):'.
            \       '(toupper(@_fgcolor@[1:])))."}{"))'
let s:texstyleend=
            \'repeat("}", '.
            \   '((@inverse@)?'.
            \       '(2):'.
            \       '((@bgcolor@!=#"")+1)))'
let s:format={
            \'begin':        '\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}'.
            \                '\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}'.
            \                '\usepackage[HTML]{xcolor}'.
            \                '\pagecolor[HTML]{%''toupper(@_bgcolor@[1:])''%}'.
            \                '\color[HTML]{%''toupper(@_fgcolor@[1:])''%}'.
            \                '\begin{document}{\ttfamily\noindent',
            \'line':         '%>'.s:texstylestart.".".
            \                     s:texescape.".".
            \                     s:texstyleend,
            \'lineend':      '\\',
            \'end':          '}\end{document}',
            \'strescape':    s:texescape,
        \}
call s:_f.format.add('latex-xcolor-clone', s:format)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Only tabulators and nonbreakable spaces seem to cause problems, but I can replace them first. Not sure if this qualifies for a bug report.

Comment: @highsciguy What do you mean? Tab characters are replaced with spaces, they are not kept. Non-breaking spaces should not cause problems, but unless you do `set list listchars=nbsp:_` they will be included as-is. If you do they will be included as `_` highlighted using SpecialKey (currently: even if you do `set hl=8:ErrorMsg` which will make vim highlight this it as `ErrorMsg`).

Comment: The set list command helps for the non-breaking spaces. Could be that the tabs appear because I have them displayed in vim. In fact in the output "»" characters appear.

Comment: @highsciguy My plugin respects both 'list' and 'listchars' options (the former only to some extent: everything except extend and precedes). Thus if you have tabs appear as `»` then you have to either turn off 'list', add `set lcs=tab:\ \ ` (i.e. use spaces to show tab), turn off plugin’s `list` option on the command-line (by adding `nolist` after target format name) or turn it off globally using `let g:format_IgnoreList=1`. By default my plugin tries to make its outputs as closer to what vim shows as it can.

Comment: @highsciguy One addition: LaTeX turns `>>` into `»` so if you have `tab:?>` (`?` - any symbol) then it is likely that formatvim will show these characters where there are no. To prevent it from happening I have to alter `s:texescape` to escape `>` as well or (better) find a way to disable transformations of `>>`, `''`, ... Do you know how to do this (much better: in a given block make all characters except `\{}[]` not special)?

Comment: I am about to use it now for a real application. Two things I noticed are that apparently bold highlighted text is not bold in the latex output (even though it seems to be easily possible to achieve this on the latex side with `{\bf text}`. Furthermore, some of the long lines are not automatically broken by latex (those which contain a lot of formatting and not just text of one color). I don't know why latex does not break them.

Answer (score 0):

The `:TOhtml` command is built in Vim. It, rather obviously, generates HTML, not Latex, though.